# Angularjs Unit Test Error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, unit-testing, testing

I am new to writing unit test. I am trying simple thing, In my `saveInfo` function in controller `$scope.practice` should contain a value.

I am using webstorm to run my test. I want to check in `saveInfo` function that $scope.practice is defined or not.

test / practice.js

```
'use strict';
describe('myApp', function() {
    describe('Controller: PracticeCtrl', function () {
        var $http, $scope, $routeParams, $location, $locale, $timeout;
      // load the controller's module
        beforeEach(function () {
            // Load the controller's module
            module('myApp');

            inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
                $scope = {};
            });

        });

        it('should define a practice property', function () {
            expect($scope.practice).toBeDefined();
        });

    });
});
```

practice.js - controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('PracticeCtrl', function ($http, $scope, $routeParams, $location, $locale, $timeout) {

$scope.saveInfo = function () {
        $scope.practice = '52300099';
        Practices.updateStampApproval().updateInfo($scope.practice);  

 };

$scope.updateInfo = function () {
   ....
}

$scope.getInfo = function () {
   ....
}
```

Gives me Error :-

```
Expected undefined to be defined.
Error: Expected undefined to be defined.
```

In my controller `$scope.practice` is defined. so why it shows error.

And how to test `function` wise means how do i write test which will check only in 1 function in controller e.g. 'saveInfo'?

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing `$scope` as an empty object, and it's not being manipulated anywhere. That's why your test is failing.

What you should do:

1. Initialize your controller with a dummy `$scope`
2. Invoke each of your controller methods in each test
3. Do your assertions in each test

For example:

```
describe('myApp', function() {
    describe('Controller: PracticeCtrl', function () {
        var $http, $scope, $routeParams, $location, $locale, $timeout, practiceCtrl;

        // load the controller's module
        beforeEach(function () {
            // Load the controller's module
            module('myApp');

            inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
                $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                practiceCtrl = $controller("PracticeCtrl", {
                    $scope: $scope
                });
            });

        });

        it('should define a practice property', function () {
            $scope.saveInfo();
            expect($scope.practice).toBeDefined();
        });

    });
});
```

I hope I was clear enough to help you.

Comment: this became clear but i have one doubt...if i use a `service` in my `controller` which brings a list of practices, Will i be able to call this service in my `test.js`?

Comment: Yes. You can mock/stub it to return a few example practices, so you don't have to rely on the server's data.

Comment: i actually want the server's data...coz then i will not have to write a mock service & instead use the real service...

Comment: you can share if you know any tutorial where i can learn this step by step.....i searched google, but haven't got perfect one.

Comment: I don't exactly have any tutorial right now. And I said to not rely on the server because it could break your tests if you reinstall your app (so your DB would have no data)